# Formulation of the uncertainty principle for a system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

There is a biological system that I can indeed describe by a simple quantum Hamiltonian $H$ having eigenstates $|q\rangle$ labelled by the numbers $q$, and having energies proportional to $f(q)$ - that is a continuous function of $q$ that sends $\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb R$. The form is:

$$H|X\rangle=E_q|q\rangle$$

with

$$E_p=E_0 f(q)$$

While $|X\rangle=|x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_q\rangle$

From here obtain a partition function with $J$ analogue to temperature $T$ and $K$ analogue to $k_B$ Boltzman constant:

$$Z(J)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty exp \left( \frac{-E_i}{KJ}\right)$$

I have never done before formulating the uncertainty principle derived from equations like above. May you help me with following questions:

*What are the commutators in the above case?*

*How does the formula for the uncertainty inequality look like for the above case?*

*Do I need to use standard deviations or is it possible to use directly certain commutators from the variables in the above case*

Comment: What biological system behaves quantum mechanically?

Comment: biological clocks

Comment: How about a link? I've never heard of quantum mechanics applied to biological clocks.

Comment: It is a research field I am working on. There is rarely about it. There is certain discrete oscialltors that can be brought in the above form. The question above is generic and could be reagrded as to a bosonic multi particle state; so the details of the biological oscillators not relevant as such, rather complicating the case.

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is quantum mechanics at play in your system. But you've got me interested in the possibility. If you want people to answer a question about a bosonic multipartcle state, why not ask it that way? In that case, the system is described by QM, so the uncertainty principle follows naturally from the formalism of QM. I think you need to convince people (or just yourself) that the biological system you care about is a QM system.

Comment: @Will for your interest let me explain briefly, certain biological clocks can be modelled by modular arithmetic and then encapsulated in a bosonic or fermionic model of multi-clocks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9454/discussion-between-will-and-al-hwarizmi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Commutators are simply how two QM operators acting on $|q\rangle$ behave when acting in opposite orders (i.e., is $\hat{A}\hat{B}|q\rangle=\hat{B}\hat{A}|q\rangle$ or no). Thus, your question is largely unanswerable because it depends entirely on $|q\rangle$, $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$.

(2) Uncertainty can be derived from the commutators. Denoting $\langle A\rangle$ as the expectation value of the operator $\hat{A}$ on $|q\rangle$, then your uncertainty for non-commuting operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ (that is, $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=i\hat{C}$) is
$$
\left(\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\langle B^2\rangle-\langle B\rangle^2\right)^{1/2}\geq \frac{1}{2}\left|\langle C\rangle\right|
$$
Usually one writes $\left(\Delta A\right)^2=\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2$ to get it in the normal form. So, again, this question entirely depends on $\hat{A}$, $\hat{B}$, and $|q\rangle$.

(3) I am not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: thanks for your response. I did not know that $f(q)$ is significantly necessary. In the simplest case $f(q)=\ln q$ and $q \in \Bbb N$. *Does that help to identify the commutators?* The third question you answered already by the second answer.

Comment: Again, it depends on the operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$. These could be position operators $\hat{x}$, momentum $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\partial_x$, energy $\hat{E}=i\hbar\partial_t$, and so on.

Comment: @KyleKanos : Your operators have to be observable (hermitian operators)